# speech to text conversion in android

Tags: android, speech-to-text

i want to develop apps based on speech to text conversion.can you please share your suggestions and how to develop this app

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably a good start:

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/speech-input.html

Comment: Would that also work for Music Fingerprint Matching? Please check my latest question.

Comment: This link is not working anymore , can you please give me the working link .

Answer (score 3):

Yes it should be possible Android has a Speech to Text APi in it. Get the user input as speech and convert it into String(The API Does it for you automatically). Based on your string output you can do operations on your application.

Check this post for getting more info on speech to text API

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/09/introduction-to-text-to-speech-in.html

Comment: but in the article they write about text-to-speech, not speech-to-text

Comment: Yes i pasted that link by mistake... The correct link is already there and has been accepted as the answer