# Android Java Speech to text

Tags: java, android

Whats the best way to do speech to text.

Like You hit the button and it starts recording or something then when you stop it pastes the text in the TextBox on my applicaiton

Comment: Check out this blog post [Android - How to Implement Voice Recognition](http://www.jameselsey.co.uk/blogs/techblog/android-how-to-implement-voice-recognition-a-nice-easy-tutorial/)

Comment: edited post with real link -.-

Comment: possible duplicate of [speech to text conversion in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640781/speech-to-text-conversion-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

Try This,

[Developer link source code](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/VoiceRecognition.html)

[Articles:Speech Input](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/speech-input.html)